# How to create an incremental number based on a variable

Tags: vbscript, asp-classic

I have a classic ASP web form that is going to be used for ordering. Since I don't know which items will be ordered, I used statements to only generate the code for each item to an XML file if the quantity ordered is > 0.  The problem I'm running into is that the vendor this is being sent to wants line numbers added to each item.

I've tried using `For i=1 To VariableName`, followed by a `Next` at the end of the list of possible ordered items.  The variable name used is a field that calculates the total items ordered.  I also tried a **for while loop**, pointing to the   Here is a sample of the code for items ordered:

```
If strQty1 <> "" then 
    If strQty1 > 0 then  
       strXML = strXML & "     <ItemOut quantity=" & chr(34) & strQty1 & chr(34) & " lineNumber=" & chr(34) & i & chr(34) & ">" & strCR
       strXML = strXML & "        <ItemID>" & strCR
       strXML = strXML & "           <SupplierPartID>S1K0R205B</SupplierPartID>"  & strCR
       strXML = strXML & "        </ItemID>"  & strCR
       strXML = strXML & "           <ItemDetail>"  & strCR
       strXML = strXML & "              <UnitPrice>"  & strCR
       strXML = strXML & "                 <Money currency=" & chr(34) & "USD" & chr(34) & ">9.78</Money>"  & strCR
       strXML = strXML & "              </UnitPrice>"  & strCR
       strXML = strXML & "              <Description/>"  & strCR
       strXML = strXML & "              <UnitOfMeasure>EA</UnitOfMeasure>"  & strCR
       strXML = strXML & "           </ItemDetail>"  & strCR
       strXML = strXML & "     </ItemOut>"  & strCR
   End If
End If  
If strQty2 <> "" then 
   If strQty2 > 0 then  
       strXML = strXML & "     <ItemOut quantity=" & chr(34) & strQty2 & chr(34) & " lineNumber=" & chr(34) & i & chr(34) & ">"  & strCR
       strXML = strXML & "        <ItemID>"  & strCR
       strXML = strXML & "           <SupplierPartID>A4216070B16</SupplierPartID>"  & strCR
       strXML = strXML & "        </ItemID>"  & strCR
       strXML = strXML & "           <ItemDetail>"  & strCR
       strXML = strXML & "              <UnitPrice>"  & strCR
       strXML = strXML & "                 <Money currency=" & chr(34) & "USD" & chr(34) & ">3.96</Money>"  & strCR
       strXML = strXML & "              </UnitPrice>"  & strCR
       strXML = strXML & "              <Description/>"  & strCR
       strXML = strXML & "              <UnitOfMeasure>BX</UnitOfMeasure>"  & strCR
       strXML = strXML & "           </ItemDetail>"  & strCR
       strXML = strXML & "     </ItemOut>"  & strCR
   End If
End If
```

As you can see, I've got a LineNumber attribute I need to populate.  The Do While Loop doesn't seem to like ending at a variable.  It hangs up the form indefinitely, seemingly stuck in a permanent loop.  All examples I have found are for generating incremental numbers in succession, not anywhere near the process I'm trying to perform.

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by "all examples...are for generating incremental numbers in succession, not anywhere near the process I'm trying to perform". Do you mean that the line numbers aren't actually line numbers, but some other number? If so, what number?

Comment: Start i at zero and just after each strQty# > 0, increment i by one ( i = i +1 ).  No loops or anything else like that

Comment: All the examples I have of incrementing numbers in VBScript involve incrementing field names up to a value that is established by selecting a number from a select box to determine the number of rows and what the value of i is, adding it to a field name.  That would, for example, make it increment fieldA1, fieldA2, so that all rows on a form mailer work out based on the number of fields someone is going to submit. Any examples I have found on the internet are similar in nature. Only the line number is variable since I don't know which fields will be selected.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Start i at zero and just after each strQty# > 0, increment i by one ( i = i +1 ). No loops or anything else like that

e.g.

```
i = 0  ' Initiate the variable
If strQty1 <> "" then 
    If strQty1 > 0 then  
       i = i + 1 ' Increment it
       strXML = strXML & "     <ItemOut quantity=" & chr(34) & strQty1 & chr(34) & " lineNumber=" & chr(34) & i & chr(34) & ">" & strCR
       strXML = strXML & "        <ItemID>" & strCR
       strXML = strXML & "           <SupplierPartID>S1K0R205B</SupplierPartID>"  & strCR
       strXML = strXML & "        </ItemID>"  & strCR
       strXML = strXML & "           <ItemDetail>"  & strCR
       strXML = strXML & "              <UnitPrice>"  & strCR
       strXML = strXML & "                 <Money currency=" & chr(34) & "USD" & chr(34) & ">9.78</Money>"  & strCR
       strXML = strXML & "              </UnitPrice>"  & strCR
       strXML = strXML & "              <Description/>"  & strCR
       strXML = strXML & "              <UnitOfMeasure>EA</UnitOfMeasure>"  & strCR
       strXML = strXML & "           </ItemDetail>"  & strCR
       strXML = strXML & "     </ItemOut>"  & strCR
   End If
End If  
If strQty2 <> "" then 
   If strQty2 > 0 then  
       i = i + 1 ' Increment it
       strXML = strXML & "     <ItemOut quantity=" & chr(34) & strQty2 & chr(34) & " lineNumber=" & chr(34) & i & chr(34) & ">"  & strCR
       strXML = strXML & "        <ItemID>"  & strCR
       strXML = strXML & "           <SupplierPartID>A4216070B16</SupplierPartID>"  & strCR
       strXML = strXML & "        </ItemID>"  & strCR
       strXML = strXML & "           <ItemDetail>"  & strCR
       strXML = strXML & "              <UnitPrice>"  & strCR
       strXML = strXML & "                 <Money currency=" & chr(34) & "USD" & chr(34) & ">3.96</Money>"  & strCR
       strXML = strXML & "              </UnitPrice>"  & strCR
       strXML = strXML & "              <Description/>"  & strCR
       strXML = strXML & "              <UnitOfMeasure>BX</UnitOfMeasure>"  & strCR
       strXML = strXML & "           </ItemDetail>"  & strCR
       strXML = strXML & "     </ItemOut>"  & strCR
   End If
End If
```

Comment: I actually tried an approach similar to this.  The result was that all the line numbers were line 1.  I went ahead and tried the above-recommended approach.  The result was that the first line number was 1. All remaining line numbers were line 0.  The variable "i" isn't accumulating for each line added.

Comment: Then there must be something in your code that you are not showing us that is setting it back to 0 again, otherwise it would not do that.

Comment: You were correct.  I found the problem and the code works correctly now.  Thanks for all your help!